# Why is my child process creating a new process, and what does it inherit from its parent process?

Tags: python, process

```
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count
import time
def count(element):
    count_value = 0
    while count_value < element:
        count_value += 1

x = Process(target=count, args=(1000000000,))
x.start()
print(cpu_count())
x.join()

print(cpu_count())
print(time.perf_counter())
```

When I execute the code above I get a RunTime Error:

```
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...
```

Now my question is what does my child process inherit from its parent that such an error occurs?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking? It's starting a process because you are literally constructing and ``.start``ing a ``Process``. As the error indicates, this has nothing to do with what the child inherits from the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the main segment of your program should be under an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. This is because the function you want the new process to use is in the main file so the new interpreter tries to import the main file. This causes it to run all of the code including trying to start a new process, which is what causes the error. All of this behaviour is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming).